# "This statement" in soot

Tags: java, soot

I want to instrument the code such as I can Insert specific statement before statements like `this.property=property`. How can I find statements consists `this` keyword, for this purpose by soot library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to transform the source code which contains this statement into `jimple` file.

So you can know how soot construct `jimple stmt` to generate this `stmt`.

After this step,you can use api in [`soot.jimple.jimple`](https://ssebuild.cased.de/nightly/soot/javadoc/)

For this stmt, I think you'd need use `newAssignStmt`.